# Calling MovieClip(root) from a dynamic MovieClip instance produces error 1034

Tags: actionscript-3

NINJA EDIT:
For some reason, the same code works now, without any problem at all. I don't know what happened, or why, but I no longer have this problem

### Here's the original post:

---

To put simply, I created a MovieClip, put it with addChild() to stage, and when I tried to call this piece of code:

```
MovieClip(root).someFunction();
```

It throws Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@4034f71 to flash.display.MovieClip.

I really can't figure out why this piece of code won't work. The object itself works perfectly, as I can call functions within it (that line of code is actually within a function). It's just that piece of code that is problematic

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

EDIT:
To better illustrate the situation, here's my pieces of code:

in a MovieClip, I have this function:

```
function bombReset():void
{
    bBombIsDropped = false;
    tCarpetBombTween.gotoAndStop(0);
    this.visible = false;
    MovieClip(root).carpetBombAttack(iPosition);
}
```

And on Scene1(root, the outermost parent) I have this function:

```
function carpetBombAttack(position:int):void
{
    damagePlant(15,vTileOccupant[(position-1)]);
}
```

If I create a MovieClip instance via addChild and call bombReset in it, Flash will throw an error

If I manually drag the MovieClip onto stage, when I call bombReset, it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that the compiler doesn't know how a `MovieClip` and a `Stage` can be the same thing. Also, I'm not certain, but I believe the compiler will whine about `someFunction` not existing on the stage even if you *casted* the `stage` (aka root) correctly.

The proper way to solve this is by assigning a document class to your project and make `someFunction` a public method (class function).

The lay-mans solution (which I sometimes use when I'm being lazy) is the following

```
Object(this.stage).someFunction();
```

That works because you are *type-casting* `this.stage` in a way that makes the compiler think it's an `Object` instead of a `Stage`. `Object`s can have any number of undocumented properties and functions, thus allowing you to call items on the `Object` whether they are part of a class definition or not (and even ones that don't exist - which is where you can get yourself into trouble).

Comment: I have quite a few other MovieClips that I add manually (dragged them from the library and gave them instance names), and the MovieClip(root).someFunction code works well, that's why I'm confused.

Will try your code

Answer (score 0):

The inheritance for `Stage` is `Stage -> DisplayObjectContainer -> InteractiveObject -> ...` while `MovieClip` is `MovieClip -> Sprite -> DisplayObjectContainer -> InteractiveObject -> ...` (I'd link directly to the docs but the pages keep crashing on me).

While they share common base classes, the `Stage` and `MovieClip` classes aren't actually related, so trying to cast one as the other will fail.

As you're doing the `MovieClip(root)` type cast and not the `root as MovieClip` cast, that's why you're getting the error you're getting.

Either cast it directly to the object that has the `someFunction()` defined, use the solution defined by Jackson, or if you absolutely know it's there, you can also do `root["someFunction"]()`

Comment: the "someFunction' is just a name, the function is actually there, I have been calling the same function with the same way (MovieClip(root).someFunction()) from within quite a few other MovieClips.

By the way, what is the difference between "root as MovieClip" and "MovieClip(root)"? I thought they both typecast the object "root" as a MovieClip? I thought MovieClip(root) is just the shorter way of root as MovieClip.

Comment: `MovieClip(root)` will throw an error if `root` isn't a `MovieClip`, while `root as MovieClip` will just give you `null`. It's a preferred method of casting. The `MovieClip(root)` style of casting is mainly used by primitive to cast from one type to another. E.g.: `Number( "2" )`

Comment: I also think the problem you're having is that while the `root` can be the `stage`, it's not necessarily always the `stage`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#root - what class is the `someFunction()` function defined in?

Comment: That someFunction() is a simple function, I did not create or use any custom class for that.

Comment: See my edit in my post above, it may better illustrate my situation

Comment: The reason why it works when you drag to the stage and not from `addChild()` is that the `root` property is probably different. Can you trace out in both cases and tell me if they're the same object?

Comment: I tried again, and for some reason, THIS time, it works flawlessly.

I'm still using MovieClip(root).carpetBombAttack(iPosition), I virtually don't change anything.

Strange indeed... 

I appreciate your effort to help me. Thank you divillysausauges

Comment: hey, at least it's working :) - try using `stage` instead of `root`, as it's always consistent. that, or keep a reference somewhere to the movieclip that has the `carpetBombAttack()` function